# redux-forms pre validate before submission

Tags: reactjs, react-redux-form

I would like to validate the form before submission and display a common error in the bottom, instead of attaching error to a particular field. errros.fieldname="Age > 10". 
Upon no errors, will prompt a message to continue submission and then upon confirmation will call form-submit.

What is the correct approach to do using redux-forms?

```
 BeforeValidate(values)
  {
    if (<<some validation condition>>) {
        this.setState({err:"Error"})
        return;
    } else 
    {
        this.setState({DialogOpen:true, err:""})
    } 
  }
```

> > To display the common error message instead of attaching as error.text
> >          somewhere in render function

```
&nbsp;{ this.state.err !='' &&  
                            <span className="text text-danger"><strong>No Value selected!
</strong></span>
                    }
```

The problem is values is not defined in BeforeValidate function. The synch validate provided in redux-form does not provide a way to set the common error message. Not sure asynch-validate is the correct place. 
So I am caught. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use normal `validate` function and add `_error`. It will be error for whole form not a field.

```
const validate = ({ options }) => {
  const errors = {};
  if (options.length === 0) errors._error = 'required';
  return errors;
};
```

In your form `render` use `this.props.error` to check for form error. 
Something like this:

```
  render() {
    const { handleSubmit, onSubmit, submitting, error, submitFailed } = this.props;
    return (
      <View>
        {error &&
          <FormValidationMessage>
            {I18n.t(error)}
          </FormValidationMessage>}
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Comment: You can also return an object like `{ fieldName: 'required' }` and it will be an error attached to one field.